# Getting data from an API with a web certificate using PHP

Tags: php, api

I'm trying to get data from an API with PHP. The request format is as follows:

```
POST https://www.aidap.naimes.faa.gov/aidap/XmlNotamServlet HTTP/1.1
Content-type: application/x-www- form-urlencoded
Content-length: <input_parameter’s length>
<a blank line>
uid=<userid>&password=<password>
```

The last line are the input parameters. How can I do such a request and what should I type as "Input Parameter's length?"

This API needs a web certificate to be accessed. I have one with a format of .p12. The certificate has a password as well. Tried it on the browser and it works. How can I implement it in PHP?